# MongoDB rename or drop a collection on a SyncClusterConnection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection I want to drop / rename. I have written the following javascript to do this:

```
var now = new Date();
var runTime = now.getTime();
var newCollName = "myColl." + runTime;
db.myColl.renameCollection(newCollName);
```

When I run the script on my single node dev install the drop or rename works fine.  However when I try the same command on the real instance which is clustered and uses replicasets I get the following error:

```
Renaming myColl collection to : myColl.1449761151171
2015-12-10T15:25:55.703+0000 E QUERY    Error: write $cmd not supported in SyncClusterConnection::query for:renameCollection
at DBQuery._exec (src/mongo/shell/query.js:83:36)
at DBQuery.hasNext (src/mongo/shell/query.js:240:10)
at DBCollection.findOne (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:187:19)
at DB.runCommand (src/mongo/shell/db.js:58:41)
at DB.adminCommand (src/mongo/shell/db.js:66:41)
at DBCollection.renameCollection (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:642:21)
```

I've read the mongodb notes for drop and renameCollection, but they dont mention needing to do anything special when running the commands on clustered database.

What do I need to do to archive off a collection on a MongoDB that is structured like this?

thanks.

Comment: This is for a sharded cluster right?

Comment: Replica set I think.

Comment: Can I see the actual command you are running?